# How do I loop through using foreach for a json decoded array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, foreign-keys

```
Array
(
    [id] => 7.8803211967429E+17
    [title] => Example T-Shirt
    [body_html] => 
    [variants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6.4266704147271E+17
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7.576504846442E+17
                    [product_id] => 7.8803211967429E+17
                )

        )

    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I need to get IDs from each main array. I get this array from decoding json using:

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    $json = file_get_contents('imarasoft.net/imarasoft/abd/WebHook/response.txt');
    $arrays = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($arrays);
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        echo $array["id"];
    }
```

How can I print ID using foreach? 
i HAVE EDITED THE QUESTION AND HAVE GIVEN THE FULL ARRAY FORMAT

Comment: are you getting single array?

Comment: Actually I will get many jsons appended to a file. All I need is to get IDs from each of those json..for that I decode it and try to get the value in ID but I couldnt

For now I have only one json in the txt file

Comment: @AbdulRahman please can you put this information in your question, it is better to give the full 'story' rather than giving it in snippets in the comments.

Comment: Simply you can use `foreach` loop to go through the array

Comment: foreach($array as $key )
{
  print_r($key['id']);
  //print_r($key);
}

Thisis not giving what I needed

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work? If you have ONE array just do `$array['id']` and if you have MULTIPLE array, just do a `foreach($multiple_array as $array) { echo $array['id']; }`, no?

Comment: @AbdulRahman Please edit your question and add what you tried and what you get so we can have better idea of your problem

Comment: Its not working for me.

Comment: @AbdulRahman if it didn't work it's because the "array" you show us is not the "right" array you get, please edit your question and add the "real" array, a screen shot of how it look I don't know and show us what you tried and what result you get please

Comment: I'm just thinking, did you tried `foreach($arrays as $obj) { echo $obj->id; }` ? Maybe you don't have array but obj I don't know

Comment: @MickaelLeger : i HAVE EDITED THE QUESTION WITH MY FULL ARRAY..
i NEED TO ECHO "7.8803211967429E+17"

Comment: which ID do you want to access? inside variants or root id?

Comment: @AbdulRahman well, if you only need the first id `echo $array['id']` should works no?

Comment: <?php
set_time_limit(0);
$json = file_get_contents('http://imarasoft.net/imarasoft/abd/WebHook/response.txt');

$arrays = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($arrays);

foreach($arrays as $array){
    echo $array["id"];
}

tHIS IS WHAT i TRIED.

Comment: @AbdulRahman he can't works since your array in ONE array, so just do `$arrays = json_decode($json, true); echo $arrays['id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting more number of elements in the array then you can use below snippets. This `foreach` loop go through all the arrays and gives value of each array's key. Here you can any value like title, id, vendor, product_type etc...

If you want access `id` inside `variants` then use below code.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://imarasoft.net/imarasoft/abd/WebHook/response.txt');
$arrays = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arrays["variants"] as $array) {
    echo $array["id"];
}
```

And if you only want to access root `id` then you just need to do only one line snippet.

```
echo $arrays["id"];
```

Comment: Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: <?php
set_time_limit(0);
$json = file_get_contents('http://imarasoft.net/imarasoft/abd/WebHook/response.txt');

$arrays = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($arrays);

foreach($arrays as $array){
    echo $array["id"];
}

Comment: Do you want get id inside variants?

Comment: If I understand a foreach is useless since his JSON array is ONE array, he has multiple array only in `$array['variants']` so he should do `echo $array['id']` and he will get `7.8803211967429E+17` as he wants, no?

Comment: If you want to get root `id` then you can use `$arrays['id']`. If you want to use `id` inside `variants`  then you have to use `foreach($arrays["variants"] as $array){ echo $array["id"]; }`

Comment: nO, i NEED TO GET THE id FIELD VALUE

Comment: Which `id` `{
  "id": 788032119674292900,` or `"variants": [
    {
      "id": 642667041472714000,`?

Comment: You can just use `echo $arrays["id"];` this statement, this will work. Check I have updated my answer

Comment: @AbdulRahman, worked my answer? Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped. if still didn't work then let me know

Comment: WORKS..!!
Thanks Ya